# Necesito saber si un String es una subcadena de otro String en Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

```
subSTR :: String -> String -> Bool
```

Eso es lo que llevo, pero no sé como comparar las posiciones de cada String.

Comment: En resumen, no tienes nada. Tienes que considerar `String` como una lista y chequear si una lista está contenida en la otra.

Answer (score 1):

El problema tiene enfoques diferentes. Lo primero es que se puede generalizar a cualquier lista, no sólo a *strings* (lista de caracteres). En el caso general, la signatura sería:

```hs
isInclude :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

El enfoque más típico de haskell es usar recursividad para ir reduciendo el problema en cada paso:

```hs
isInclude :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isInclude [] _ = True
isInclude _ [] = False
isInclude xs ys | xs == take (length xs) ys = True
                | otherwise = isInclude xs (tail ys)
```

En el primer caso, consideramos que la lista vacía siempre está incluida en cualquier otra lista.
En el segundo caso, consideramos que en la lista vacía no hay ninguna lista incluida, con excepción de la propia lista vacía (que ya estaría considerada en el primer caso).
En el tercer caso, chequeamos si la lista es igual al fragmento inicial de la misma longitud. Si no lo es, reiteramos el proceso con la cola.

Se puede hacer más corta usando la función `tails`. Esta función la podríamos importar del módulo `Data.List`, pero se puede expresar rápidamente de la siguiente manera:

```hs
tails :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails [] = [[]]
tails xs@(_:ys) = xs : tails ys
```

Por poner un ejemplo:

```
tails "Hola" --> ["Hola","ola","la","a",""]
```

Los elementos de esta lista los acortamos a la longitud de la lista a comparar:

```hs
[take (length xs) ys' | ys' <- tails ys]
```

Y añadimos la comparación:

```hs
[xs == take (length xs) ys' | ys' <- tails ys]
```

Lo último que falta es saber si alguna de estas comparaciones es True:

```hs
or [xs == take (length xs) ys' | ys' <- tails ys]
```

Si lo ponemos todo junto:

```hs
isInclude :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isInclude xs ys = or [xs == take (length xs) ys' | ys' <- tails ys]
```

Refactorizando:

```hs
isInclude :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isInclude xs ys = any (xs==) . map (take $ length xs) $ tails ys
```

Refactorizando un poco más:

```hs
isInclude :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isInclude xs = any (xs==) . map (take $ length xs) . tails
```